# R integrate: returns wrong solution (is using wrong quadrature points?)

Tags: r, integrate, numerical-integration

I have a function in R which I am trying to integrate, but for some (extreme) values of the function parameters, `integrate` returns the incorrect solution. I believe the issue may be that `integrate` selects improper quadrature points for some of these extreme values, but first I will provide demonstrate the issue.

The function I wish to integrate is the following.

```
integrandFunc_F <- function(x, func_u, func_u_lowerBar, 
  func_u_upperBar, func_mean_v, func_sigma_v, func_sigma_epsilon, 
  func_sigma_y, func_gamma, func_rho) {
#print(x);
p <- 1 - pnorm(func_u_upperBar,x,func_sigma_y);
q <- pnorm(func_u_lowerBar,x,func_sigma_y);
p <- p*(1-func_rho); q <- q*(1-func_rho);
alpha <- ifelse(func_gamma*(p+q) == 0, 0, pmax((func_gamma*p-q)/(func_gamma*(p+q)), 0));
g <- ifelse(x > func_u, dnorm(x,func_mean_v,sqrt(func_sigma_v^2 + func_sigma_epsilon^2))/(1-pnorm(func_u,func_mean_v,sqrt(func_sigma_v^2 + func_sigma_epsilon^2))), 0);
output <- alpha*g;
output
}
```

When I try to calculate the following, I get the correct solution of 1:

```
integrate(integrandFunc_F, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, func_u= 8, func_u_lowerBar= 8, 
  func_u_upperBar= 8, func_mean_v= 30, func_sigma_v= .1, func_sigma_epsilon= 2, 
  func_sigma_y= 1, func_gamma= 1/1.1, func_rho= .05)
```

However, when I try to calculate the following, I get the incorrect solution of 0:

```
integrate(integrandFunc_F, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, func_u= 8, func_u_lowerBar= 8, 
  func_u_upperBar= 8, func_mean_v= 50, func_sigma_v= .1, func_sigma_epsilon= 2, 
  func_sigma_y= 1, func_gamma= 1/1.1, func_rho= .05)
```

Above I indicated I believe the issue may have to do with the selection of quadrature points. If you uncomment `#print(x)` in the function above, you can see in the `func_mean_v = 30` case, `integrate` settles on quadrature points that are relatively large/near 30. However,  in the `func_mean_v=50` case, after a few iterations `integrate` selects quadrature points that are near 0. Quadrature points near 0 are inappropriate to evaluate this function, which incorporates a normal distribution with mean at `func_mean_v.`

Any ideas on how to address this issue? Why would `integrate` iterate to quadrature points near 0 in some cases? Note, the choices of `func_mean_v = 30` and `func_mean_v = 50` are admittedly extreme parameters for this function, however I need to be able to calculate such cases correctly.

Comment: have you tried lowering the tolerance for the convergence of integrate? There is no general rule for adaptive numerical integration that will work for all integrands (how could it know where the integrand is non-zero between -Inf and +Inf?) so you sometimes [need to help it](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/puzzle-with-integrate-over-infinite-range-td2548525.html).

Comment: I've tried lowering `rel.tol` and increasing the number of `subdivisions`. Neither have fixed the issue. Is there a way to provide `integrate` with a set of quadrature points to start with? For a normal distribution, it should not be difficult to know where the integrand is non-zero.

Comment: if you know where the integrand is non-zero, shifting and optional rescaling of the integration variable is the way to go imho; it will help `integrate` immensely.

Comment: `integrate()` cannot use your own quadrature points: it uses a specific (Gauss) quadrature rule, so the weights are only appropriate for the corresponding nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could shift the integration variable to centre the peak,

```
wrapper <- function(x, func_mean_v, ...)
   integrandFunc_F(x+func_mean_v, func_mean_v=func_mean_v, ...)


integrate(wrapper, rel.tol = 1e-8, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, func_u= 8, func_u_lowerBar= 8, 
          func_u_upperBar= 8, func_mean_v= 50, func_sigma_v= .1, func_sigma_epsilon= 2, 
          func_sigma_y= 1, func_gamma= 1/1.1, func_rho= .05)
# 1 with absolute error < 1.3e-09
```

Comment: Thanks @baptiste. Can you edit to show the exact code that gave you the solution of 1? Is wrapper a function with integrandFunc_F defined inside of it? Or are they defined separately?

Comment: this _is_ the exact code! you might be confused by the lack of `{}` for the wrapper, they're not necessary for one-liners.

Comment: Thanks! So I keep my original definition of `integrandFunc_F` from before and then in addition define the function `wrapper` as you have done here.