# Problems with integrate() returning integral of 0

Tags: r, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am having trouble with an integral that, as far as I can tell, should be well-behaved, but is incorrectly returning `0` when I try to integrate over `-Inf` to `Inf`. Consider the following R code:

```
t = 466
N = 50
df = 198
rscale = sqrt(2)/2
delta = seq(50, 80, len=100)
log.const=-13.94309

f = Vectorize(function(delta,t,N,df,rscale,log.const=0)
  exp(dt(t,df,ncp=delta*sqrt(N),log=TRUE) + dcauchy(delta,scale=rscale,log=TRUE) - log.const),
"delta")

integrate(f, -Inf, Inf, t = t, N = N, 
        df = df, rscale = rscale, log.const = log.const)
```

This integral returns 0. The function appears well behaved, from the plot:

```
plot(delta,f(delta,t,N,df,rscale,log.const), ty='l')
```

and if I integrate with a "reasonable" range, the integral appears correct:

```
integrate(f, 50, 80, t = t, N = N, 
        df = df, rscale = rscale, log.const = log.const)
```

And everything works fine if one sets `t=465` instead! Why would `integrate()` have problems with this integral? It seems to be having trouble finding the mass of the function, but I don't know of any way to tell the `integrate()` function where to look. Perhaps there is another numerical approach I can take?

Comment: if you can estimate the center of mass analytically, I would suggest you do a change of variables to bring this closer to 0. `integrate()` only samples a (necessarily) finite number of points, and if you're unlucky none fall into the non-zero part of your integrand. You can also decrease the tolerance (rel.tol), but that doesn't seem enough here.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/25585316/471093

Comment: I had this happen once and ended up using a simple grid over a reasonable range and doing it using trapezoids. In my case precision was not terribly important. It also must have been that integrate had trouble even when given the reasonable range, or perhaps I just didn't think of that. I'll be interested to see what others suggest.

Comment: This occurs for reasons given baptiste's link as well as a few other questions.  Once you choose `-Inf,Inf`, the number of sample points in the regions where your function has a decent value may drop to a point where the result is poor.  Since you know your function is practically zero over most of the range, why not just integrate over some finite limits?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually defined in this case? It seems to me, that you are calculating expectation of some function `g(delta)` in the cauchy distribution.

Comment: @J.R., yes, it does exist. It is a marginal likelihood (which is indeed an expectation from the Cauchy, but one that exists; it's just the normalizing constant for the corresponding posterior)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, the advice on the help for integrate says to use (-Inf, Inf) when that is what is desired: "When integrating over infinite intervals do so explicitly, rather than just using a large number as the endpoint. This increases the chance of a correct answer – any function whose integral over an infinite interval is finite must be near zero for most of that interval." (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/integrate.html)

Comment: @baptiste looks like shifting the function so that it sits around 0 does the trick!

Comment: good to hear. Note that you can put a `print(delta)` in your function to see what points are actually evaluated.